# Android Espresso doesn't perform onData calls

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am trying to create a helper method which performs a selection (button press).

```
public void performPoseSelection(String roomName, int selection) {
        onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
                .atPosition(selection)
                .onChildView(withId(R.id.btn))
                .perform(click()); 
}

public void testPickPose() throws InterruptedException{
        performPoseSelection("White Room", 0);
        performPoseSelection("White Room", 1);
        performPoseSelection("White Room", 1);
        performPoseSelection("White Room", 0);
}
```

What I am finding is that the results are inconsistent. There are times when a selection is not made at all! Other times, the the test is performed correctly. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Too little information to answer really. Could be anything. Timing issues not accounted for, Adapter contract not fulfilled by your Adapter, etc. Please provide more context.

Comment: The issue turned out to be a timing issue, as a delay of 500ms at the beginning of performPoseSelection seemed to resolve the issue.